# How to parse hierarchy data

Tags: oracle, go

In Oracle, I have such table:

```
| organization_id | ogranization_name | parent_id | level |
|-----------------|-------------------|-----------|-------|
| 1               | Facebook          |           | 0     |
| 2               | Instagram         | 1         | 1     |
| 3               | Whatsapp          | 1         | 1     |
| 4               | Dynamic           | 2         | 2     |
| 5               | Google            |           | 0     |
```

This table show the hierarchy of organizations. I need to create a tree-like nested JSON response in my Go application:

```
[
    {
        "organization_id": 1
        "ogranization_name": "Facebook",
        "childs": [
            {
                "organization_id": 2,
                "ogranization_name": "Instagram",
                "childs": null
            },
            {
                "organization_id": 3,
                "ogranization_name": "Whatsapp",
                "childs": [
                    {
                        "organization_id": 4,
                        "ogranization_name": "Dynamic",
                        "childs": null
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "organization_id": 5
        "ogranization_name": "Google",
        "childs": null
    }
]
```

I make query to Oracle database. I also create struct. My question is how to know if an organization has children or not?

**main.go:**

```
type Organisation struct {
    ID       int            `json:"organization_id"`
    Name     string         `json:"ogranization_name"`
    Children []Organisation `json:"childs"`
}

rows,err := db.Query("select * from ORG_TABLE")

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}

var organizations []Organization

for rows.Next() {
    var organization Organization

    err = rows.Scan(&organization.ID, &organization.Name, ???)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
}

organizations = append(organizations, organization)
```

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/how-to-connect-a-go-program-to-oracle-database-using-goracle  and encoding/json

Comment: Requests like this for libraries, tools, or other resources are off-topic.

Comment: @Vorsprung hello! I don't know why you give me this link. The question wasn't about how to connect golang application to oracle database. Can you check my post again please?! I add some code.

Comment: @Flimzy can you check my post again please? I add some code. Do you have any ideas how I can check of organization has any child?

Comment: Your question has not fundamentally changed. "What methods or packages do you use to parse such data quickly and efficiently?" is off-topic.

Comment: @Flimzy I removed that sentence from the post. My question is how to know if organization has childs or not?

Comment: I have removed my close vote.

Comment: I have edited your question to change the incorrect "childs" to "children", but I didn't modify that in your code, since that's machine-read. You might consider correcting that in your code, though. :)

Comment: Query the table twice.  On the first query build a Map lookup such that if a parent is filled in the id is appended to a list that is indexed by the parent id.  Then query again and use the Map to generate the child output

Comment: @Vorsprung there must be some infinite loop cuz level depth not set, right?! Could you show me your idea with example please?

Comment: Don't have experience with Oracle but this is working on the json-object provided: https://play.golang.org/p/cMW-r0V3nKA

Comment: @ABri hello! I believe you can use any other database which is comfortable for you. Unfortunately the main problem in my case to create json-object from database data. Do you have any ideas how to make it in my case? Can you check my post?! I add code which I use right now.

Comment: @Nurzhan Nogerbek: Did you had a look at the playground code. If the db-response is like in your above example, it should work.

Comment: @ABri yes, I check it. My database response is not JSON. Database return data which I need to convert to JSON. You can notice from my code that I make sql query and then start to parse result like `for rows.Next() {***}`. So what I need to put from your code in that loop?!

Comment: @ABri but the question is not about Oracle. The same structure `rows.Next() {***}` you need to set if use any other database. You are right, somehow I need create `[]byte`. The question is how? :)

Comment: The problem is that they wouldn't be nested as in your example.

Comment: Every record would be as separate object in array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189859/discussion-between-abri-and-nurzhan-nogerbek).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found solution:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "sort"

    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

type Organization struct {
    ID       int             `json:"organization_id"`
    Name     string          `json:"organization_name"`
    Rang     int             `json:"organization_rang"`
    Children []*Organization `json:"children"`
}

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./database")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer db.Close()

    rows, err := db.Query("select ORGANIZATION_ID,ORGANIZATION_NAME,ORGANIZATION_RANG,PARENT_ORGANIZATION_ID from ORG")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer rows.Close()

    orgs := map[int]*Organization{}

    for rows.Next() {
        organization := &Organization{}
        var parentID sql.NullInt64

        if err = rows.Scan(&organization.ID, &organization.Name, &organization.Rang, &parentID); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        if parentID.Valid {
            if parentOrg, ok := orgs[int(parentID.Int64)]; ok {
                parentOrg.Children = append(parentOrg.Children, organization)
            } else {
                orgs[int(parentID.Int64)] = &Organization{ID: int(parentID.Int64)}
                orgs[int(parentID.Int64)].Children = append(orgs[int(parentID.Int64)].Children, organization)
            }
        }

        if _, ok := orgs[organization.ID]; ok {
            orgs[organization.ID].Name = organization.Name
            orgs[organization.ID].Rang = organization.Rang
            continue
        }

        orgs[organization.ID] = organization
    }

    IDs := []int{}
    for k := range orgs {
        IDs = append(IDs, k)
    }
    sort.Ints(IDs)

    organizations := []Organization{}
    for _, ID := range IDs {
        if len(orgs[ID].Children) > 0 && orgs[ID].Rang == 1 {
            organizations = append(organizations, *orgs[ID])
        }
    }

    content, err := json.MarshalIndent(organizations, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(content))
}
```